# How to get a React Redux state value from the reducer?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-thunk, redux-reducers

In Redux, I currently have a state that looks something like the following.

```
{
  activeConversation: "Jim"
  conversations: (7) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
}
```

I'm also using socket.io to send messages to other users.

```
export const newMess = (body) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  try {
    const {activeConversation} = getState();
    if (!body.conversationId) {
      dispatch(addConversation(body.recipientId, data.message));
    } else {
       dispatch(setNewMessage(data.message, activeConversation));
    }
    sendMessage(data, body, activeConversation);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};
```

From here, I then call my reducer function. The problem is with the variable `activeConversation`. Because I'm passing it through socket.io from thunk, it results in both users having the same `activeConversation` value which is not what I want (I want them to have different values). The problem is that I'm having trouble accessing the state. I got the state originally from thunk but that leads to the `activeConversation` from user 1 being passed to user 2 and I need to get the `activeConversation` value from each user. I'm wondering if it's possible to get the `activeConversation` state value from my reducer as opposed to thunk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not very clear. However, if you want to get other state slices or the entire state in the reducer, you can use [Sharing data between slice reducers](https://redux.js.org/usage/structuring-reducers/beyond-combinereducers#sharing-data-between-slice-reducers).

E.g.

```js
import { combineReducers, createStore } from 'redux';

const SET_MESSAGE = 'SET_MESSAGE';
export const setNewMessage = (message, sender) => {
  return {
    type: SET_MESSAGE,
    payload: { message, sender: sender || null },
  };
};

function activeConversationReducer(state = 'Jim', action) {
  return state;
}
function conversationsReducer(state = [1, 2, 3], action) {
  return state;
}
function userReducer(state = { id: 8, username: 'josh', email: '' }, action) {
  return state;
}

const combinedReducer = combineReducers({
  activeConversation: activeConversationReducer,
  conversations: conversationsReducer,
  user: userReducer,
});

function crossSliceReducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_MESSAGE: {
      console.log('entire state:', state);
      // do something with state
      return state;
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

function rootReducer(state, action) {
  const intermediateState = combinedReducer(state, action);
  const finalState = crossSliceReducer(intermediateState, action);
  return finalState;
}

const store = createStore(rootReducer);
store.dispatch(setNewMessage('data', 'sender'));
```

Execution result:

```
entire state: {
  activeConversation: 'Jim',
  conversations: [ 1, 2, 3 ],
  user: { id: 8, username: 'josh', email: '' }
}
```